# rpm packaging: files installed using rpm but not found by other rpm which requires it

Tags: rpm, specifications, rpmbuild

problem: my rpm package installs the following but doesn't finds it when other package uses it as a dependency:

```
sudo rpm -qlp libjaeger-16.0.0-3641.g0b61b1fc.el8.x86_64.rpm

/usr/lib64/libjaegertracing.so.0
/usr/lib64/libjaegertracing.so.0.6.1
/usr/lib64/libopentracing.so.1
/usr/lib64/libopentracing.so.1.6.0
/usr/lib64/libthrift.so.0.13.0
```

and for rpm package with this package being mentioned in **Requires** field, it does specify what shared libs you need:

```
Error: 
 Problem 1: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides libjaegertracing.so.0()(64bit) needed by ceph-common-2:16.0.0-3642.g90dc7b19.el8.x86_64
  - nothing provides libopentracing.so.1()(64bit) needed by ceph-common-2:16.0.0-3642.g90dc7b19.el8.x86_64
  - nothing provides libthrift.so.0.13.0()(64bit) needed by ceph-common-2:16.0.0-3642.g90dc7b19.el8.x86_64
```

but as you see, even after understanding which file are provided by Required rpm, it is not able to resolve the location for these files.

considerations and checkes I did:

1. being build in the same platform (64bit)
2. experimentally checked in a dummy spec file >> works fine with `rpm --provides`  also listing shared libs,

```
    rpm -q --provides libjaeger2-1-1.x86_64
    libjaeger2 = 1-1
    libjaeger2(x86-64) = 1-1
    libjaegertracing.so.0()(64bit)
    libopentracing.so.1()(64bit)
    libthrift.so.0.13.0()(64bit)
```

but when I do the same for main source rpm created
I do not see shared libs in provides:

```
❯ sudo rpm -q --provides libjaeger-16.0.0-3641.g0b61b1fc.el8.x86_64.rpm

libjaeger = 2:16.0.0-3641.g0b61b1fc.el8
libjaeger(x86-64) = 2:16.0.0-3641.g0b61b1fc.el8
```

how do I make sure rpm is able to resolve and find these shared libraries?

relevant part of spec file:

```
%if %{with jaeger}
%files -n libjaeger
#will have to change with find_package method
%{_libdir}/libopentracing.so.*
%{_libdir}/libthrift.so.*
%{_libdir}/libjaegertracing.so.*

%post -n libjaeger -p /sbin/ldconfig
%postun -n libjaeger -p /sbin/ldconfig

%files -n libjaeger-devel
%{_includedir}/thrift
%{_includedir}/jaegertracing
%{_includedir}/opentracing
%{_libdir}/libopentracing.so
%{_libdir}/libthrift.so
%{_libdir}/libjaegertracing.so
%endif



 %package -n libjaeger
    Summary:    Ceph distributed file system client library
    %if 0%{?suse_version}
    Group:      System/Libraries
    %endif
    Obsoletes:  libjaeger < %{_epoch_prefix}%{version}-%{release}
    %description -n libjaeger
    Ceph is a distributed network file system designed to provide excellent
    performance, reliability, and scalability.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably disabled automatic provides. See: http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-depend-auto-depend.html

You either have to enable it again by deleting the line with `AutoReqProv` or explicitly write it in spec:

```
  Provides: libjaegertracing.so.0()(64bit)
  Provides: libopentracing.so.1()(64bit)
```

The first is preferred as the second is hard to maintain.

Comment: yep, explicit specification did help resolve the conflict, but I did not have `AutoReqProv` disabled, that's what I don't understand, maybe would need some digging with find-provides script(as find-requires seems to resolve things correctly), thanks!